# Linux - TCP Socket Creation Time & Idle Time

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, netstat

I've a scenario where thousands of tcp connections are preset at the server, with most of them in established state. Expected number of connections is less than 100 as the server is not exposed to web traffic and just talking to another set of servers. 
Though netstat provides list of open connections, I'm looking for information like when was a socket created and how long it has been idle. Is there any tool/utility that can provide this information?

Comment: I am curious why you need that information

Comment: I'm investigating the issue of high number of connections. I'm hoping this will help me identify if sockets timeouts and configurations are being followed or not, plus if connections are getting reused properly as we expect the connections to be persistent.

Comment: You need to *cure* the *problem.* Clearly it is at the client end, but you can at least administer some aversion therapy. It is generally essential for a TCP server to use a request timeout, and close the offending socket if it triggers.